# How can I end input by enter a Blank Character in PYTHON ( raw_input() )?

Tags: python

Such as : Input two integer a and b,separated by a space in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.split()` to split a string at spaces and then you can use `map` or a `list comprehension` to convert the numbers into integers:

```
>>> n1,n2 = map(int,raw_input().split())
100 20
>>> n1
100
>>> n2
20

>>> n1,n2 = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
123 43
>>> n1
123
>>> n2
43
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = raw_input('Input two integer a and b,separated by a space: ')
Input two integer a and b,separated by a space: 5 9
>>> [int(n) for n in s.split()]
[5, 9]
```